# How do I call a function to print a Turtle's coordinates on keypress?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to print new coordinates for my turtle every time it moves, either in the console or on canvas, while at the same time erasing the old coordinates. How do I call a function to print coordinates on screen after each keypress?

This is what I have so far:

```
def writer(x, y):
    turtle1.write((x, y), align='center', font=FONT)
    turtle1.undo()

wn.onkey(writer, "Up")
wn.onkey(writer, "Down")
wn.onkey(writer, "Left")
wn.onkey(writer, "Right")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just wishful thinking.  You're missing your imports and other vital details (e.g. declarations of `turtle1` and `FONT`).  You're assuming that `onkey()` passes coordinates to its event handlers (it doesn't).  Much more setup is needed to do what you want.  I would recommend two turtles, one that responds to keyboard events by visibly moving on the screen, and a second one that sits at the origin writing out the coordinates of the first turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 18

FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def move_up():
    wn.onkey(None, 'Up')  # disable handler inside handler
    turtle1.sety(turtle1.ycor() + 5)
    writer()
    wn.onkey(move_up, 'Up')

def move_down():
    wn.onkey(None, 'Down')
    turtle1.sety(turtle1.ycor() -5)
    writer()
    wn.onkey(move_down, 'Down')

def move_left():
    wn.onkey(None, 'Left')
    turtle1.setx(turtle1.xcor() - 5)
    writer()
    wn.onkey(move_left, 'Left')

def move_right():
    wn.onkey(None, 'Right')
    turtle1.setx(turtle1.xcor() + 5)
    writer()
    wn.onkey(move_right, 'Right')

def writer():
    turtle2.undo()
    turtle2.write(turtle1.position(), align='center', font=FONT)

turtle1 = Turtle('circle')
turtle1.penup()

turtle2 = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle2.penup()
turtle2.sety(-FONT_SIZE / 2)
turtle2.write(turtle1.position(), align='center', font=FONT)

wn = Screen()

wn.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
wn.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
wn.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
wn.onkey(move_right, 'Right')

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```